# Refresh a div variable on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, form

***I have the following code***

```
<div class="viewAllEmailOverlay" onclick="jQuery(this).fadeToggle();jQuery('.viewAllEmailModal').fadeToggle();return false;" style="display: none; position: fixed; _position: absolute; top: 0; _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop)); left: 0px; z-index: 9997; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.8;" />
    <div class="viewAllEmailModal" style="display: none; position: fixed; _position: absolute; top: 20%; _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop)+20); left: 20%; bottom: 18%; width: 60%; min-width: 500px; padding: 2em; z-index: 9998; background: white; border-radius: .5em; overflow: auto;" >
<apex:form id="ViewAllEmailsForm">
<apex:pageBlock title="Invitation Mail" id="invite1">
            <apex:pageMessages />
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Model.invitationemail}" var="**mail**">
<apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!mail.Id}">{!mail.Subject}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
<div style="float: right; margin-top: 25px;">           
                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn"  id="CancelButton" onclick="window.reload(); return false;"/>
            </div>
       </apex:form>  
    </div>
```

**invitationemail** is a variable of the class which has a list.(through query)
This div given above pops up on a click of a link of each row. For the second click the variable **mail** is holding the first value. Then it gets refreshed after sometime . I wan to know if there is a way to refresh the div variable **mail** on the click of the submit button.

Comment: Could you please provide complete code...

Comment: Sounds like you could use the native Visualforce rendered and re-render to achieve this. JQuery is great, but prone to problems in SalesForce. http://www.oyecode.com/2013/04/how-to-re-render-part-of-visualforce.html